# how to display user data in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

here am looking for the particular data of logged in user to display in their profile i don't know how to do that. this is the error i get "'User' object is not iterable"
please help me .

views.py

```
def users_homepage(request):
    merchant=Merchant.objects.filter(request.user)
```

models.py
class Merchant(models.Model):

```
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    shop_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone_number=models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

dashboard.html

```
{%for merchan in merchant%}
<h1>{{merchan.shop_name}}</h1>
{%endfor%}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify which field you're filtering on, change the View to:

```
def users_homepage(request):
    merchant=Merchant.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```